# YouTube Analytics API - Onprem oath2 GCP Application working fine with 1 channel but failing with other channels Error 403: org_internal

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

A GCP internal app authorization using Oauth2 token to fetch YouTube channel Analytics data.

Onprem application is using the oath2 credential created in GCP to authenticate into YouTube channels and extract data for analytics using YouTube Analytics API docs. It is working fine for 1 of the channels however failing with the following Error 403: org_internal for the other YouTube channels.